# How to access virtual serial port using PHP?

Tags: windows, php, 3g

I'm trying to send an SMS via a 3G Modem with php, but I can only access com1. I can't access com3 (the 3G modem) because it's a virtual serial port.

Does anyone know how to access a virtual serial port using PHP?

Answer (score 1):

All serial ports should be accessible the same way, virtual or not.

If accessing `COM3` does not work, try `COM3:` or `\\.\COM3` – as in `fopen("\\\\.\\COM3", ...)`.

Comment: i do not need to set something in php.ini or httpd.conf? u already did it?